# Invalid identifier error, Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've been trying to write this query for 1 hour, but the SQL Developer always throws an error.

```
SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Drivers d
  JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
  GROUP BY d.driver_name
  HAVING cnt = MAX(cnt);
```

> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>
> Error at last line, column 20.

So I've figured out another solution, but another error is thrown:

```
SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM Drivers d
  JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
  GROUP BY d.driver_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(COUNT(*));
```

> 935. 00000 -  "group function is nested too deeply"
>
> Error at last line, column 25.

EDIT: thanks gyus, you are awsome, almost all the replies are working, but I have to choose one...

Comment: you want to get total count of what?

Comment: Use a derived table, or a sub-select.

Comment: I'd like to get those drivers, who are the most frequently included in the Fastest_drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT driver_name, cnt
FROM (SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () as MAXcnt
      FROM Drivers d JOIN
           Fastest_laps fl
           ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
      GROUP BY d.driver_name
     ) d
WHERE cnt = MAXcnt;
```

You can also express this using `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT driver_name, cnt
FROM (SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Drivers d JOIN
           Fastest_laps fl
           ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
      GROUP BY d.driver_name
     ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The advantage to this approach is that you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead and get exactly one row, even if multiple drivers have the same maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I ordered by `cnt` in descending order. And then selected the top row from it. You can edit the query as `rownum <=2` to get the top 2 rows and so on.

```
           with tbl1 as
           (SELECT d.driver_name as driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM Drivers d
            JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
            GROUP BY d.driver_name
            order by cnt desc
            )
            select driver_name,cnt from tbl1
            where cnt = (select cnt from tbl1 rownum=1)
```

Comment: this query return only one driver, athor need all drivers who have max value

Comment: Edited the answer to match your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Oracle supports this, but please give it a try:

```
SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Drivers d
  JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
GROUP BY d.driver_name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Or use a common table expression:

```
with cte as
(
SELECT d.driver_name as driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Drivers d
  JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
GROUP BY d.driver_name
)
select driver_name, cnt
from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your query into a inline view to be able to query `cnt`:

```
select *
from   (
         SELECT d.driver_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
         FROM Drivers d
         JOIN Fastest_laps fl ON d.ID_driver = fl.ID_driver
         GROUP BY d.driver_name
       ) x
group
by     driver_name, cnt
having cnt = MAX(cnt);
```